# After Microsoft disabled the RPS for exchange my code is throwing 'System.Management.Automation.PSNotImplementedException'

Tags: c#, powershell-3.0, remote-connection, exchange-management-shell

After Microsoft has disable the use of RPS (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/deprecation-of-remote-powershell-in-exchange-online-re-enabling/ba-p/3779692) my code has broken.

Below is the C# code.

```
    HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    var tenantId = ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Client.GetAsync(ConnectionConst.wsManTokenIssuer + pSCredential.UserName.Split('@')[1] + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)).authorization_endpoint.ToString().Split('/')[3];
    PublicClientApplicationBuilder pcaBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId);
    pcaBuilder.WithTenantId(tenantId);
    var tokenResult = pcaBuilder.Build().AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(new[] { scope }, pSCredential.UserName, pSCredential.Password).ExecuteAsync().Result;
    System.Security.SecureString secureStringToken = new System.Security.SecureString();
    foreach (char c in ("bearer " + tokenResult.AccessToken))
    {
        secureStringToken.AppendChar(c);
    }

    PSCredential _shellCredential = new PSCredential(domainInfo.UserName, secureStringToken);();
    String wsManURIConnectionString = "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid?DelegatedOrg=" + domainInfo.Domain + "&BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true";
    WSManConnectionInfo _wsManConnectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(wsManURIConnectionString), ConnectionConst.wsManShellURI, _shellCredential);
    _wsManConnectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
    _wsManConnectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 4;
    Runspace _runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(_wsManConnectionInfo);
    _runspace.Open();
```

At line Runspace _runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(_wsManConnectionInfo); I am getting 'System.Management.Automation.PSNotImplementedException' Exception.